# How to use multiple setqury using solr?

Tags: solr

How to use multiple setQuery on solr?
i want to search name="din" and staus="active" and email="din"
am using like this

```
if(isset($_GET["name"]) && $_GET["name"]!=""){
            $query->setQuery('name:*'.$_GET["name"].'*');
        }

        if(isset($_GET["email"]) && $_GET["email"]!=""){
            $query->setQuery('email:*'.$_GET["email"].'*');
        }
        if(isset($_GET["role"]) && $_GET["role"]!=""){
            $query->setQuery('role:*'.$_GET["role"].'*');
        }
        if(isset($_GET["status"]) && $_GET["status"]!=""){
            $query->setQuery('status:'.$_GET["status"]);
        }
```

But its not giving proper response 
let me know how to use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`->setQuery()` sets the query. If you want to set several conditions, you'll have to provide all of them. Also remember that any `$_GET` variable can contain spaces and similar values, and should be properly escaped.

You can build a query by keeping each term by itself, before merging it into a single query string at the end:

```
$queries = array();

if (!empty(if($_GET["name"])) {
    // add proper escaping here, so you don't escape * as well.
    $queries[] = 'name:*'.$_GET["name"].'*';
}

// you probably want to check that there actually is any queries here as well
$query->setQuery(join(" AND ", $queries));
```

Comment: @DineshKumar Great! Accept the answer if it works :-)

Comment: Hii Let me know how to search exact word ?

Comment: New question - create a new question. However, exact searches are the default. If you want to match a field *completely*, use a StrField - only exact matches (and not single words) will match.

Comment: ok check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37456205/how-to-update-the-document-on-solr-6-0