# How to update the document on solr 6.0?

Tags: solr, solarium

I am using `solr 6.0` version.

This is my data

```
{
    "id" : "14",
    "solrid" : "solr|school|14",
    "name" : "test update solr 14",
    "status" : "pending",
    "state" : "Andhra Pradesh",
    "board" : "CISCE",
    "updated" : "2016-05-26T02:24:25Z",
    "pincode" : "0"
}
```

I want to update the data on document as per id.
example i want to change the name

```
$doc = $update->createDocument();


   $doc["id"] =$id;
            $doc["name"]="school";
            $update->addDocument($doc);
            $update->addCommit();
            $client->update($update);
```

This code is correct? Or i want to use other flow.
PHP Solarium code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, basically the flow is correct. You can always check the solarim examples gist at https://gist.github.com/basdenooijer/894286.

Alternatively you can do something like this:

```
$update = $client->createUpdate();
$document = $update->createDocument();
$document->setKey('id', $id);
foreach ($data as $field => $value) {
    if ($field == 'id') {
        continue;
    }
    $document->setField($field, $value, null, 'set');
}
$update->addDocument($document, true, 1500);
$result = $client->update($update);
```

Comment: am getting this error {"responseHeader":{"status":400,"QTime":4},"error":{"metadata":["error-class","org.apache.solr.common
.SolrException","root-error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException"],"msg":"Invalid Date String
:'2016-05-30 12:07:12'","code":400}}

Comment: But i lost other filed data i want to update particular filed.

Comment: Pass the datetime in the UTC format, take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18831782/solr-invalid-date-string-exception and http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_4_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/schema/DateField.html